# Passing bc into a variable isn't working right for me in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, syntax, bc

I think I'm going crazy, I have a different script that's working fine with the usual way of passing the output of bc into a variable but this one I just can't get working.

The relevant bits of code are this:

```
PERCENT_MARKUP=".5"

$percentonumber=$(bc -l <<<"$PERCENT_MARKUP/100")
echo "Percent to number = $percentonumber"

$numbertomultiply=$(bc -l <<<"$percentonumber + 1")
echo "Number to multiply = $numbertomultiply"

$MARKUP=$(bc -l <<<"$buyVal * $numbertomultiply")
#$MARKUP=$(bc -l <<<"$buyVal * (1+($PERCENT_MARKUP/100))")
echo "Markup = $MARKUP"
```

Originally, I only had the second to last line that's currently commented out but I broke it down to try and troubleshoot.

The error I'm getting when I'm trying to run it is:

`./sell_zombie_brains: line 65: =.00500000000000000000: command not found`

where the .0050000000000000 is replaced by the output of bc. I've even tried the following at multiple points in the file including right after #!/bin/bash with and without -l

```
$test=`bc -l <<<"1"`
echo "$test"
echo
$test=$(bc -l <<<"1")
echo "$test"
echo
$test=$(echo "1"|bc -l)
echo "$test"
echo
```

And each one outputs ./sell_zombie_brains: line 68: =1: command not found

I'm really at my wits end. I don't know what I'm missing here. Any insight as to why it's behaving this way is appreciated.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thank you, I'll save this. It will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign variables with the sigil `$` :

instead of

```
$percentonumber=$()
```

it's

```
percentonumber=$()
```

---

If you are a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) beginner, some good pointers to start learning :

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info
[FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ)
[Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)
[Ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)
[bash hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/)
[quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
[Check your script](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

And avoid people recommendations saying to learn with tldp.org web site, the tldp bash guide -ABS in particular) is outdated, and in some cases just plain wrong. The [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and the [bash-hackers' wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Activate_Bash.27s_Debug_Mode) are far more reliable.

Comment: No worries, maybe switching over languages makes mistakes (I think of perl by example)

Comment: You give me too much credit lol. I'm just pinning it on tired eyes and too many distractions.